# Android VideoView as background

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-videoview

I would to use a VideView as background in my layout.

So I would to have this videoView fullscreen and I need to add on this view other 'components' like TextView, EditView, ImageView...etc.

This is an example of my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".Login"
    android:alpha="0.9">

    <VideoView
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/VideoView">
    </VideoView>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:alpha="0.9">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:src="@drawable/logoweb"/>

etc...
```

In this way I can't see the other components... only the video...

Answer (score 1):

Try using FrameLayout.

FrameLayout always places things one on top of the other and always in reference to the upper lefthand corner,you can use something like this to acheive the above result

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/VideoView"

    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:src="@drawable/logoweb"
    />
```

Comment: If I use a FrameLayout I can't see the fullscreen video

Comment: add a relative layout on top of it and change the layout_height of the frame layout and that of newly added to relative layout to fill_parent hopefully you will be able to see it in full screen

Comment: can be more precise please? I'm new in Android

Comment: Arslan Sohail's answer should be marked as correct.